# Как интегрировать плагин СДЭК в rbspayment для оплаты доставки на сайте?

Tags: worpdress

Суть такова что есть сайт где установлен плагин Метод доставки СДЭК для Woocommerce(1) и плагин Оплата банковской картой для woocommerce(2) так вот я никак не могу интегрировать (1) в (2) раздельно все работает СДЭК показывает стоимость доставки но я хочу чтобы можно было оплатить доставку на сайте а остальную сумму при доставке .Как интегрировать ?